# Is there standard method for managing camel cased strings in groovy?

Tags: groovy

For example groovy converts `getSomeProperty()` method to `someProperty`.

I need the same for my string. `prefixMyString` converted to `myString`.
Is there standard way to do so?

Comment: Also groovy manages upperCASEDParts well. I need it too.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy doesn't actually convert `getSomeProperty()` into `someProperty`.  It only converts the other way, turning `someProperty` into `getSomeProperty()`

It does this using the `capitalize(String property)` method on `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MetaClassHelper`.  You can run this in the console to see it work:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MetaClassHelper.capitalize('fredFlinstone')
// outputs 'FredFlintstone'
```

The full conversion, including adding `set`, `get`, or `is`, can be found in the class `groovy.lang.MetaProperty`, under the methods `getGetterName` and `getSetterName`.

To convert the other way, you'll have to write your own code.  However, that's relatively simple:

```
def convertName(String fullName) {
    def out = fullName.replaceAll(/^prefix/, '')
    out[0].toLowerCase() + out[1..-1]
}

println convertName('prefixMyString') // outputs: myString
println convertName('prefixMyOTHERString') // outputs: myOTHERString
```

Just change the `prefix` to meet your needs.  Note that it's a regex, so you have to escape it.

---

**EDIT**: I made a mistake.  There actually is a built-in Java method to decapitalize, so you can use this:

```
def convertName(String fullName) {
    java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(fullName.replaceAll(/^prefix/, ''))
}
```

It works nearly the same, but uses the built-in Java class for handling the decapitalization.  This method [handles uppercase characters a little differently](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29), so that `prefixUPPERCASETest` returns `UPPERCASETest`.